# Manually providing missing maven/ivy dependency with sbt

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I have a maven dependency in my *sbt* project that had one of its dependencies apparently unpublished (I have filed [an issue](https://github.com/typesafehub/netty-http-pipelining/issues/13) for that problem already).

I still have a copy of that dependency and I'm trying to figure out how to get *sbt* to pick it up from a project specific location, rather than the local ivy cache, since this project needs to build on machines that don't have a pre-populated ivy store.

I've tried placing it into the project's *lib* directly but that does not seem to get considered as part of the dependency resolution of sub-dependencies.

**EDIT:** I rephrased this question to be about *sbt* dependency management rather than the specific library I am having problems with

Regarding Duplication: This is not a question about publishing un-managed jars to a local maven repository. It is about how to satisfy a dependency of a managed dependency via an unmanaged jar.

Answer (score 1):

Saw in the referenced issue that your problem might have been solved already, but in case it would be useful anyway:

Files added to `lib/` is added to the classpath but there is no clever logic that will parse pom-files/ivy-descriptors and it will not be added to ivy's dependency resolution.

What you may be able to do though could make a local ivy cache for just this dependency inside of the project directory where you publish it according to ivy cache structure and then add that with a sbt resolver, something like this:

```
// with repo in projdir/local-netty-repo/
resolvers += Resolver.file("some-name", file("local-netty-repo"))
```

Comment: Yes, the underlying issue i was having has been resolved, but i would still like a process for similar situations. Let me try that out and see if it works